# div element not respecting an inline list's padding

Tags: html, css, layout, inline, padding

I'm using an inline list, and I noticed that that the div on the next line won't respect its padding (i.e. it is drawn right through the li elements' border). Is there anything I can do about that?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      li {
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
      }

      div {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>World</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      Hello, World!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline elements **are not affected by top and bottom padding** (see [why](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)).

Instead you can make them `inline-block`:

```
li {
   display: inline-block;
   zoom: 1; /* for IE */
   *display: inline; /* for IE */
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but this stretches the enclosing ul (which has some styles applied to it in the real page) across the width of the whole page, making it look weird. Is there a way to keep it small?

Comment: @futlib, I don't know why the `<ul>` would do that. Can you post the actual CSS?

Comment: It's the above, with just two changes: inline-block instead of inline for the li as you suggested, and a border (e.g. "border: 1px solid red") for the ul. If I use inline-block or inline for the ul, it works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

For the `li`, specify `display: inline-block;` instead of just `inline`